# Xcode 6 crashes when attempting to run swift app

Tags: swift, xcode6

So ever since I updated to Xcode 6, I can no longer run my app that I have been building with swift on my iPhone. Every time I attempt to build it through Xcode, it builds, but when it tries running it on my phone Xcode crashes.

I first noticed this during the beta, but I switched back to Xcode 5 hoping they would fix it by the final release. However, I tried again last week using Xcode 6.3, but the problem still occurs. This time, however, I cannot go back to Xcode 5 because I updated my iPhone to iOS 8.3 hoping it would fix the error, but Xcode 5 cannot build for a device running iOS 8.3.

I tested older projects of mine that only use objective-c and they were able to run fine in Xcode 6.3 so I believe this is either a swift error or something wrong with the settings in my project.

Does anyone know what could be causing this crash?

Here is the crash log from Xcode: (It was too long so I removed some of the binary images lines)

```
Process:               Xcode [82739]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.3.1 (7703)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-7703000000000000~4
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       812230896
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [82739]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             (null)
PlugIn Identifier:       (null)
PlugIn Version:          ??? (???)

Date/Time:             2015-05-12 13:03:11.408 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        79DF5A6F-8E9D-6D50-A9EA-DCB2F2C0543C

Sleep/Wake UUID:       7D8874B4-3207-4F59-9427-4E86EDB3DD3E

Time Awake Since Boot: 1500000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       2000 seconds

Crashed Thread:        16  Dispatch queue: DBGLLDBLauncher Serial Queue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes:       0x000000000000000a, 0x000000014f16b000

VM Regions Near 0x14f16b000:
    mapped file            000000014ecb2000-000000014ee53000 [ 1668K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  /private/var/folders/*/*.csstore
--> mapped file            000000014ee53000-000000014f43e000 [ 6060K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/8.0 (12A365)/Symbols/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
    MALLOC_LARGE           000000014f6d9000-000000014f755000 [  496K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6D1002
closed document

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b714412 _kernelrpc_mach_vm_deallocate_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b718153 mach_vm_deallocate + 25
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8a26a -[OS_dispatch_data dealloc] + 23
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff87d9189c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a7957fe -[NSNib dealloc] + 63
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff87d9189c objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 236
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff87d77e8f (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 575
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90c6a6f2 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 50
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff91754583 __NSFirePerformWithOrder + 344
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90cb0127 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90cb0080 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca2188 __CFRunLoopRun + 872
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca1bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff895b256f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff895b21ee ReceiveNextEventCommon + 179
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff895b212b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a6139bb _DPSNextEvent + 978
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a612f68 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
18  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x000000010c4fcdda -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a608bf3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a585354 NSApplicationMain + 1832
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff870d35c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71a232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8ca6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7144de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca2eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca237b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca1bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff8e90c220 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7193fa __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7144de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca2eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca237b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca1bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff91747a59 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011732cf2c -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 974
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7144de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca2eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca237b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca1bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff91747a59 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011731e8c6 +[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection startServiceBrowsers] + 213
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7144de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca2eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca237b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca1bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8a6db66b _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 7:: DYMobileDeviceManager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7144de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca2eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca237b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca1bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff91747a59 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff917bd17f -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
7   com.apple.GPUToolsMobileFoundation  0x000000011f92d89b -[DYMobileDeviceManager _deviceNotificationThread:] + 134
8   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b719136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000116df6426 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b719136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000116df6426 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b719136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000116df6426 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b719136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000116df6426 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b719136 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   com.apple.Xcode.DevToolsCore    0x0000000116df6426 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] + 456
2   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff916f5dc2 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: com.apple.CoreAnimation.render-server
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7144de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8cdf604f CA::Render::Server::server_thread(void*) + 198
3   com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff8cdf5f82 thread_fun + 25
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: Dispatch queue: parsing queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71451a semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba90c55 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 213
2   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010ddf2d7a -[DTXMessageParser waitForMoreData:incrementalBuffer:] + 87
3   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010ddf29b8 -[DTXMessageParser parseMessage] + 50
4   com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices  0x000000010ddf2776 __43-[DTXMessageParser initWithMessageHandler:]_block_invoke + 35
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8e323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba89c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8d365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8eecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8c6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba9afe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2840d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7144de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71364f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca2eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca237b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90ca1bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff90d59671 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.DebugSymbols          0x00007fff8929eb8f SpotlightQueryThread(void*) + 463
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 16 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: DBGLLDBLauncher Serial Queue
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86c05188 strlen + 72
1   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115475790 Pool::GetConstCString(char const*) + 26
2   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001154751ed lldb_private::ConstString::ConstString(char const*) + 65
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001155881c0 ObjectFileMachO::ParseSymtab() + 8306
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001155860c2 ObjectFileMachO::GetSymtab() + 158
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001155e895f SymbolFileSymtab::CalculateAbilities() + 43
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115631367 lldb_private::SymbolFile::FindPlugin(lldb_private::ObjectFile*) + 229
7   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115631a25 lldb_private::SymbolVendor::AddSymbolFileRepresentation(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::ObjectFile> const&) + 111
8   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001155e9b68 SymbolVendorMacOSX::CreateInstance(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, lldb_private::Stream*) + 1558
9   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156318f9 lldb_private::SymbolVendor::FindPlugin(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, lldb_private::Stream*) + 43
10  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001154b8e3e lldb_private::Module::GetSymbolVendor(bool, lldb_private::Stream*) + 114
11  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156b1215 PlatformDarwin::LocateExecutableScriptingResources(lldb_private::Target*, lldb_private::Module&, lldb_private::Stream*) + 119
12  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001154ba34f lldb_private::Module::LoadScriptingResourceInTarget(lldb_private::Target*, lldb_private::Error&, lldb_private::Stream*) + 173
13  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115674216 lldb_private::Target::ModuleAdded(lldb_private::ModuleList const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&) + 140
14  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001154bb48f lldb_private::ModuleList::AppendImpl(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module> const&, bool) + 135
15  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115673b41 lldb_private::Target::GetSharedModule(lldb_private::ModuleSpec const&, lldb_private::Error*) + 1579
16  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x00000001156733c3 lldb_private::Target::SetExecutableModule(std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Module>&, bool) + 619
17  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011567c26c lldb_private::TargetList::CreateTargetInternal(lldb_private::Debugger&, char const*, lldb_private::ArchSpec const&, bool, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Platform>&, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Target>&, bool) + 1656
18  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011567b842 lldb_private::TargetList::CreateTargetInternal(lldb_private::Debugger&, char const*, char const*, bool, lldb_private::OptionGroupPlatform const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Target>&, bool) + 3014
19  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011567ac71 lldb_private::TargetList::CreateTarget(lldb_private::Debugger&, char const*, char const*, bool, lldb_private::OptionGroupPlatform const*, std::__1::shared_ptr<lldb_private::Target>&) + 49
20  com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000113923581 lldb::SBDebugger::CreateTarget(char const*, char const*, char const*, bool, lldb::SBError&) + 267
21  com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerLLDB   0x00000001138a0282 __24-[DBGLLDBLauncher start]_block_invoke + 1491
22  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010bfb5e56 __DVTDispatchBarrierAsync_block_invoke + 106
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8e323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba89c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8d365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8eecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
27  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8c6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba9afe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
29  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
30  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2840d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71930a __read_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86c46f4b __srefill1 + 24
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff86c407db fgets + 104
3   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x0000000115565bc1 lldb_private::IOHandlerEditline::GetLine(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, bool&) + 341
4   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011556603c lldb_private::IOHandlerEditline::Run() + 176
5   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011547d46c lldb_private::Debugger::ExecuteIOHanders() + 86
6   com.apple.LLDB.framework        0x000000011547f4c8 lldb_private::Debugger::IOHandlerThread(void*) + 14
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a268 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a1e5 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2841d thread_start + 13

Thread 18:: Dispatch queue: DTDKExecuteInSession 6578661eaf5b2d3815805a3f21a42376ca16a6be
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b7188ca __connect + 10
1   com.apple.mobiledevice          0x00000001173e79bd USBMuxConnectByPort + 111
2   com.apple.mobiledevice          0x0000000117459176 _connect_to_port + 146
3   com.apple.mobiledevice          0x0000000117458eff AMDeviceConnect + 193
4   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x000000011731d9df __58-[DTDKRemoteDeviceConnection _fetchValueForDomain:andKey:]_block_invoke_2 + 25
5   com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation      0x000000010bfb5e56 __DVTDispatchBarrierAsync_block_invoke + 106
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8e323 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba89c13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8d365 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1100
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8eecc _dispatch_queue_invoke + 202
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba8c6b7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 463
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8ba9afe4 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 91
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2a637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2840d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8b71994a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff8eb2840d start_wqthread + 13

Thread 16 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0xfffffffffffff800  rbx: 0x000000014f16afdb  rcx: 0x000000000000000b  rdx: 0x000000014f16afdb
  rdi: 0x000000014f16b000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000126242550  rsp: 0x0000000126242550
   r8: 0x000000011fa66ff0   r9: 0x000000011fa5dcc0  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0xffffffffd3cc252e
  r12: 0x000000014f16afdb  r13: 0x0000000000000002  r14: 0x00007f96e2917570  r15: 0x0000000000073762
  rip: 0x00007fff86c05188  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x000000014f16b000

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x10bda4000 -        0x10bda4ff7  com.apple.dt.Xcode (6.3.1 - 7703) <0C2DD9A8-9E10-3D11-A163-5F7BEE3305E0> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x10bdb0000 -        0x10c1f5fff  com.apple.dt.DVTFoundation (6.3.1 - 7703) <21925B6B-7213-3AD1-9E3F-C256FF2CF796> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
       0x10c3bb000 -        0x10c6dbff7  com.apple.dt.DVTKit (6.3.1 - 7703) <BDEF6426-6038-3E29-8D91-E79B4CAEADDF> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework/Versions/A/DVTKit
       0x10c8cd000 -        0x10cd10ff7  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation (6.3.1 - 7703) <801CD389-4440-3766-AC01-FC0377B1A474> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IDEFoundation
       0x10cfd6000 -        0x10d829ff7  com.apple.dt.IDEKit (6.3.1 - 7703) <84F1DF4E-F82D-3DE4-91DE-7894FF71D2A8> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit
       0x10dde1000 -        0x10ddfeff7  com.apple.dt.instruments.DTXConnectionServices (1.0 - 57514) <C75495F2-1411-332E-B97D-06CD124049CC> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/Versions/A/DTXConnectionServices
       0x10de24000 -        0x10de63ff7  com.apple.framework.ConfigurationProfiles (7.1 - 750) <8695E204-8EFF-347A-8721-8FDD33A441BA> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConfigurationProfiles.framework/Versions/A/ConfigurationProfiles

....
....
.... More here, but removed because of character limit
....
....




External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 175
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 84314954
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 82

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=417.3M resident=155.1M(37%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=262.2M(63%)
Writable regions: Total=1.9G written=510.0M(26%) resident=629.6M(33%) swapped_out=71.2M(4%) unallocated=1.3G(67%)

REGION TYPE                        VIRTUAL
===========                        =======
Activity Tracing                     2048K
CG backing stores                    14.9M
CG image                             25.3M
CG shared images                      400K
CoreAnimation                         252K
CoreData Object IDs                  4100K
CoreImage                               8K
CoreServices                          808K
CoreUI image data                     312K
Dispatch continuations               16.0M
Foundation                             16K
Image IO                              256K
JS JIT generated code                   8K
JS JIT generated code (reserved)      1.0G        reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Kernel Alloc Once                       8K
MALLOC                              751.6M
MALLOC (admin)                         32K
Memory Tag 242                         12K
Memory Tag 249                        156K
Memory Tag 251                         16K
OpenCL                                 52K
SQLite page cache                    28.0M
STACK GUARD                          56.1M
Stack                                24.7M
VM_ALLOCATE                          17.4M
WebKit Malloc                         464K
__DATA                               45.5M
__IMAGE                               528K
__LINKEDIT                          107.1M
__TEXT                              310.2M
__UNICODE                             552K
mapped file                         583.2M
shared memory                           4K
===========                        =======
TOTAL                                 2.9G
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space        1.9G


Model: MacBookPro8,2, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.69f4
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533642465238432D48392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.24)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1
Network Service: Ethernet Adaptor (en3), Ethernet, en4
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK7559GSXF, 750.16 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB Receiver
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 22.1
```

EDIT: The issue seems to occur when using SceneKit. In my case, when I have an SCNView in the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the issue was a hardware problem. My computer recently crashed and had issues starting up again, so I took it into the apple store and there was a known issue with my MacBook Pro model. After getting some components replaced, everything appears to run fine.